# jQuery over loaded ajax content

Tags: jquery, dom, fancybox

I'm using fancybox plugin to show bigger images.

if I put in the html page

```
 <a id="fancy" href='img_big.jpg'><img scr="img.jpg" /></a>
```

it works fine, but if load with `load()` the same lines fancy box is not applied.

how can i fix that?

Comment: You may want to add some additional example with how you're calling `load()`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much detail, but you mention `.load()`. I assume this means you're dynamically updating the document after its initial load, and not seeing the fancybox plugin being applied to the new elements.

Fancybox [Issue 18](http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/issues/detail?id=18) (Google Code) describes some struggles to get the plugin working with jQuery's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Comment 14 of the thread describes someone's apparent success by applying a class to the anchor tags in question, then using `.live()` to bind the fancybox behavior to the mouseover event on those selected tags. You'd make sure your `<a>` tags have a class of `fancybox`, and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('a.fancybox').live('mouseover', function(){ $(this).fancybox() });
});
```

We don't know what version of jQuery or fancybox you're using, so you may also look into the [Live Query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) solution described in Comment 5 of that same thread.